# Photoshop to illustrator drag and drop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm working with a hand calligraphy piece which I've cleaned up in photoshop - removed specs etc and used magic wand to delete the background. When I try and then drag and drop this into illustrator with the two files side by side it shows a little white arrow that suggests I can drag it directly, however the artwork doesn't appear in Illustrator. The drag and drop trick works with text but not with my artwork?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49983/getting-transparent-images-from-photoshop-into-illustrator/

Comment: Welcome Laura! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers

Answer (score 1):

I tried drag and dropping images into Illustrator myself to no avail, but is it possible for you to simply "place" the image into the Illustrator file? It is the same function as in InDesign, but Illustrator does not give it a shortcut.

[image]

Just go to File -> Place, and then open your Photoshop file into the Illustrator file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Move tool (v)? All I did was drag the entire canvas from Photoshop to Illustrator (both CC 2014) and it worked fine.

Otherwise, copy and paste or Place, as Anjelli suggested, should work fine too.

Comment: Thanks I can't get it to work with the move tool still, but the method above works.